# group by statement not highlighitng in proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following code

```
  proc sql;
        create table wantedData as select label,count(value) as count 
        from bins left join work.test
        on start<=value<=end
        group by label
        order by start;
    quit;
```

The thing is **group by statement is not highlighting**  which causes it to give the wrong data.

**BTW I am using SAS 9.1**

Comment: what happens when you substitute `group by label` with `group by 1` i.e., grouping by 1st column in the `select` statement- which is an alternative syntax. BTW I don't think the issue is caused by `group by statement is not highlighting` - highlighting or not is purely down to the editor. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Can you give more details: sample of input data, result? Not highlighting some key words is  not necessarily a sign of some problem with code, might be  just a harmless "bug" of the code editor.

Comment: Can you `count(value)` when using `GROUP BY`? Shouldn't you `count(*)`?

Comment: Highlighting is certainly irrelevant, except if it's indicating you have a problem otherwise.

Comment: @Turophile You can certainly `count(value)`. `Count(*)` would give you the total row count (I don't recall if it's total total, or total row count excluding rows with ALL null values), `count(value)` gives you the count of rows where value is not missing.  `count(distinct value)` is a third option, the count of unique values of `value`.

Comment: For me that highlights fine and looks correct, depending on your data and what you're trying to do.  You'd have to clarify more with additional data to get a useful answer, otherwise I'm going to recommend closing the question.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I have seen (and probably used) the `count(column)` syntax before, but it just stood out to me as possibly part of the problem. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is

```
order by start
```

Since `start` is not in the `group by`, it is likely performing a remerge to implement that rule.  While most SQL flavors will simply disallow selecting by a variable not in the `group by`, which is what you are doing when using `order` (implicitly selecting), SAS will instead take the group by result and then join that back to the original table containing the non-group-by variable, thus returning more rows (unless the group by is not reducing the row count).

You either need to remove that `order` statement, or you need to use some sort of summary function, like `order by max(start)`.